# How do I get an ethernet connection with Automotive Grade Linux (Halibut 8.0.0)?

Tags: networking, ethernet

I'm trying to get a basic ethernet connection with Halibut 8.0.0

```
sa8155:~# ifconfig eth0 up
sa8155:~# udhcpc
udhcpc: started, v1.29.3
udhcpc: sending discover
udhcpc: sending select for 10.0.0.112
udhcpc: lease of 10.0.0.112 obtained, lease time 604800
/etc/udhcpc.d/50default: Adding DNS 75.75.75.75
/etc/udhcpc.d/50default: Adding DNS 75.75.76.76
```

It seems to get an ip address assigned via DHCP,
and the DNS address is comcast so it does appear to be hitting my comcast router

```
sa8155:~# ifconfig eth0
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:b6:e9:de:7a  
          inet addr:10.0.0.112  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2601:647:4201:a2b0:250:b6ff:fee9:de7a/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:128 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:140 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:22180 (21.6 KiB)  TX bytes:25954 (25.3 KiB)
```

but I cannot ping other computers on my network

```
sa8155:~# ping 10.0.0.196
PING 10.0.0.196 (10.0.0.196): 56 data bytes
ping: sendto: Network is unreachable
sa8155:~#
```

nor can other computers on my network ping 10.0.0.112

```
    >ping 10.0.0.112
PING 10.0.0.112 (10.0.0.112): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
```

and my router has no record of device sa8155, so I'm skeptical that DHCP is actually working.

Here's what I see in /etc/resolv.conf:

```
sa8155:~# cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by Connection Manager
sa8155:~#
```

It seems that the [Connection Manager, known as connman](https://docs.automotivelinux.org/docs/en/halibut/architecture/reference/security/part-5/4-Services.html), is controlled via connmanctl.

According to the AGL documentation https://wiki.automotivelinux.org/connman:

[image]
But "connmanctl services" returns an empty list for me:

```
sa8155:~# connmanctl services

sa8155:~# connmanctl technologies
/net/connman/technology/ethernet
  Name = Wired
  Type = ethernet
  Powered = True
  Connected = False
  Tethering = False
sa8155:~#
```

According to [this cheatsheet](https://gist.github.com/kylemanna/6930087), the list should look something like this:

[image]

I'm not sure how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a default installation, ConnMan will connect to a wired ethernet connection without any additional setup or interaction. It monitors kernel network interface events and brings the interface up automatically, including setting a default gateway and default routes. It also has built into it a dhcp client and dns forwarder. Having said that, it all depends on how AGL Halibut has compiled/configured it. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with that distribution.

For your reference, typically, an installation of ConnMan includes a symlink from `/etc/resolv.conf` to `/var/run/connman/resolv.conf`. The contents of the file is

```
# Generated by Connection Manager
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

You can find the status of your network interfaces using the `ip address` command.

It may also be useful to look in the logs generated by ConnMan. You may want to stop connman (depends on the init system, or just kill the connmand process). Then run it from the command line to see what is happening.

Comment: Thank you. In my particular case it looks like it does indeed create an ethernet connection as you suggest. At least initially. It drops the connection later for some unknown reason. Fortunately periodic rebooting restores the connection.